# Group C# Monthly DataTable Quarterly

Tags: c#

I currently have a DataTable that is has my data that I need in a [monthly view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saMdq.png). What I am trying to do is group this data into a quarterly view, grouped on the ActivationYear, ActivationQuarter, BranchYear, and BranchQuarter.

I need the most recent (last complete month for the quarter) values from AmountFinanced and CurrentBalance. However, I need the **sum** of the Payments for each month in the quarter.

Here is an example of what I have monthly:

```
ActivationDate  |  CurrentBranchDate  |  AmountFinanced  | Payments  | CurrentBalance
1/1/16          |  1/30/16            |  $10,000         |  $100     |  $9,800
1/1/16          |  2/29/16            |  $10,000         |  $0       |  $9,900
1/1/16*         |  3/31/16*           |  $10,000*        |  $2,000*  |  $7,800*
1/1/16*         |  4/30/16*           |  $10,000*        |  $1,000*  |  $6,800*
2/1/16          |  2/29/16            |  $5,000          |  $0       |  $5,200
2/1/16*         |  3/31/16*           |  $5,000*         |  $500*    |  $4,700*
2/1/16*         |  4/30/16*           |  $5,000*         |  $200*    |  $4,500*
```

Here's the desired result when grouped quarterly (the rows above with the * are the rows I used for CurrentBalance):

```
ActivationY | ActivationQ | BranchY | BranchQ | AmountFinanced | Payments | CurrentBalance
2016        | 1           | 2016    | 1       | $15,000        | $2,500   | $12,500
2016        | 1           | 2016    | 2       | $15,000        | $1,200   | $11,300
```

I have tried looping through the Monthly table, but I seem to get duplicates and incorrect sums (ex: adding all of the amount financed columns giving me $40,000 financed when it should only be $15,000).

Here is the updated code based on jdweng's answer:

```
var testResults = monthlyTable.AsEnumerable()
                        .GroupBy(x => (x.Field<DateTime>("ActivationDate").Month - 1) / 3)
                        .Select(x => new
                        {
                            ActivationYear = x.FirstOrDefault().Field<DateTime>("ActivationDate").Year,
                            ActivationQuarter = ((x.FirstOrDefault().Field<DateTime>("ActivationDate").Month - 1) / 3) + 1,
                            BranchYear = x.FirstOrDefault().Field<DateTime>("CurrentBranchDate").Year,
                            BranchQuarter = ((x.FirstOrDefault().Field<DateTime>("CurrentBranchDate").Month - 1) / 3) + 1,
                            AmountFinanced = x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Field<DateTime>("CurrentBranchDate")).Select(y => y.Field<decimal>("AmountFinanced")).FirstOrDefault(),
                            CurrentBalance = x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Field<DateTime>("CurrentBranchDate")).Select(y => y.Field<decimal>("CurrentBalance")).FirstOrDefault(),
                            Sum_of_Payments = x.Sum(y => y.Field<decimal?>("Payments"))
                        }).ToList();
```

I'm still getting an incorrect AmountFinanced and CurrentBalance. Do I need to be grouping on the CurrentBranchDate as well?

@jdweng, here is the data that I am using:

```
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("11/01/2016"), DateTime.Parse("11/30/2017"), 57000, 0, 53639.4 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("01/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("11/30/2017"), 52000, 0, 52000 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("03/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("11/30/2017"), 28000, 0, 27160.82 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("04/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("04/30/2017"), 77200, 0, 76190.96 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("04/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("05/31/2017"), 77200, 0, 76190.96 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("04/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("06/30/2017"), 77200, 0, 76190.96 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("06/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("06/30/2017"), 98450, 0, 98450 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("04/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("07/31/2017"), 77200, 0, 76190.96 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("04/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("08/31/2017"), 77200, 0, 76190.96 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("04/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("09/30/2017"), 77200, 0, 76190.96 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("06/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("07/31/2017"), 98450, 0, 98450 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("06/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("08/31/2017"), 98450, 0, 98450 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("06/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("09/30/2017"), 98450, 0, 98450 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("04/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("10/31/2017"), 77200, 0, 76190.96 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("04/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("11/30/2017"), 77200, -1947.7, 74616.01 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("06/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("10/31/2017"), 98450, 0, 98450 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("06/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("11/30/2017"), 98450, 0, 98450 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("08/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("08/31/2017"), 20000, 0, 20000 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("08/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("09/30/2017"), 20000, 0, 20000 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("08/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("10/31/2017"), 20000, -1631.58, 18540.78 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("08/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("11/30/2017"), 20000, 0, 18540.78 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("10/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("10/31/2017"), 25000, -509.55, 24490.45 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("10/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("11/30/2017"), 25000, 0, 24490.45 });
```

Here is the modified item I'm calling:

```
var quarterResults = monthlyTable.AsEnumerable()
                    //.GroupBy(x => (x.Field<DateTime>("ActivationDate").Month - 1) / 3)
                    //.GroupBy(x => new { ActivationMonth = (x.Field<DateTime>("ActivationDate").Month - 1) / 3, ActivationYear = x.Field<DateTime>("ActivationDate").Year })
                    .GroupBy(x => new { ActivationQuarter = (x.Field<DateTime>("ActivationDate").Month - 1) / 3, ActivationYear = x.Field<DateTime>("ActivationDate").Year, BranchQuarter = (x.Field<DateTime>("CurrentBranchDate").Month - 1) / 3, BranchYear = x.Field<DateTime>("CurrentBranchDate").Year })
                    .Select(x => new[]
                    {
                        x.FirstOrDefault().Field<DateTime>("ActivationDate").Year,
                        ((x.FirstOrDefault().Field<DateTime>("ActivationDate").Month - 1) / 3) + 1,
                        x.FirstOrDefault().Field<DateTime>("CurrentBranchDate").Year,
                        ((x.FirstOrDefault().Field<DateTime>("CurrentBranchDate").Month - 1) / 3) + 1,
                        x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Field<DateTime>("CurrentBranchDate")).Select(y => y.Field<decimal>("AmountFinanced")).FirstOrDefault(),
                        x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Field<DateTime>("CurrentBranchDate")).Select(y => y.Field<decimal>("CurrentBalance")).FirstOrDefault(),
                        x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Field<DateTime>("CurrentBranchDate")).Select(y => y.Field<decimal>
                        x.Sum(y => y.Field<decimal?>("Payments"))
                    }).ToArray();
```

If you look at the data that it generates for ActivationYear 2017, ActivationQuarter 2, BranchYear 2017, BranchQuarter 2 it gives me 77,200 as the amount financed when it should give me 175,650 (77,200 + 98,450).

Comment: show us the code you have so far, so we might be able to find the problem. would it be an option to query the data in a quarterly grouping from database, instead of grouping it in memory? obtw, blurring is not safe data protection.

Comment: I'll post the code I have in a minute. All of the data is test data, I'm just blurring it for the sake of the example. If I am able to sum the payments correctly, then the rest will be the same.

Comment: @dlatikay, also I don't think I'll be able to query it directly from SQL according to the project specifications.

Comment: looks ok to me. I think your algorithm is not as concise as it could be, but correct, but you input data prevents grouping in the way you intend, because ActivationDate and CurrentBranchDate can be in different quarters. So the loop generates a grouped row for every unique combination, not just for every quarter that occurs in ActivationDate.

Comment: @dlatikay I don't think my example shows the scenario I intend. Give me a minute to update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication31
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("ActivationDate", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("CurrentBranchDate", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("AmountFinanced", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Columns.Add("Payments", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Columns.Add("CurrentBalance", typeof(decimal));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("11/01/2016"), DateTime.Parse("11/30/2017"), 57000, 0, 53639.4 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("01/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("11/30/2017"), 52000, 0, 52000 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("03/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("11/30/2017"), 28000, 0, 27160.82 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("04/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("04/30/2017"), 77200, 0, 76190.96 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("04/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("05/31/2017"), 77200, 0, 76190.96 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("04/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("06/30/2017"), 77200, 0, 76190.96 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("06/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("06/30/2017"), 98450, 0, 98450 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("04/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("07/31/2017"), 77200, 0, 76190.96 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("04/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("08/31/2017"), 77200, 0, 76190.96 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("04/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("09/30/2017"), 77200, 0, 76190.96 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("06/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("07/31/2017"), 98450, 0, 98450 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("06/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("08/31/2017"), 98450, 0, 98450 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("06/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("09/30/2017"), 98450, 0, 98450 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("04/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("10/31/2017"), 77200, 0, 76190.96 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("04/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("11/30/2017"), 77200, -1947.7, 74616.01 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("06/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("10/31/2017"), 98450, 0, 98450 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("06/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("11/30/2017"), 98450, 0, 98450 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("08/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("08/31/2017"), 20000, 0, 20000 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("08/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("09/30/2017"), 20000, 0, 20000 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("08/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("10/31/2017"), 20000, -1631.58, 18540.78 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("08/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("11/30/2017"), 20000, 0, 18540.78 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("10/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("10/31/2017"), 25000, -509.55, 24490.45 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("10/01/2017"), DateTime.Parse("11/30/2017"), 25000, 0, 24490.45 });

            var quarterResults = dt.AsEnumerable()
                    .GroupBy(x => new { ActivationQuarter = (x.Field<DateTime>("ActivationDate").Month - 1) / 3, ActivationYear = x.Field<DateTime>("ActivationDate").Year })
                    .Select(x => new {
                        activationYear = x.FirstOrDefault().Field<DateTime>("ActivationDate").Year,
                        quarterResults = ((x.FirstOrDefault().Field<DateTime>("ActivationDate").Month - 1) / 3) + 1,
                        branchYear = x.FirstOrDefault().Field<DateTime>("CurrentBranchDate").Year,
                        branchQuarter = ((x.FirstOrDefault().Field<DateTime>("CurrentBranchDate").Month - 1) / 3) + 1,
                        AmountFinanced = x.GroupBy(y => new { ActivationDate = y.Field<DateTime>("ActivationDate")}).Select(z => z.OrderByDescending(a => a.Field<DateTime>("CurrentBranchDate")).Select(y => y.Field<decimal>("AmountFinanced")).FirstOrDefault()).Sum(),
                        CurrentBalance = x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Field<DateTime>("CurrentBranchDate")).Select(y => y.Field<decimal>("CurrentBalance")).FirstOrDefault(),
                        sum = x.Select(y => y.Field<decimal?>("Payments")).Sum()
                    }).ToArray();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you might be getting somewhere with this. The only issue that I am running into with it is that the AmountFinanced is incorrect. It's only taking the first value instead of the sum (it gives me $10,000 when it should be giving me $15,000 [$10,000 + $5,000]). The payments looks correct.

Comment: Here's what I get when I run your example: https://i.imgur.com/t4ZjV1r.png. Here's the numbers I should be getting for reference: https://i.imgur.com/LOW9N5V.png

Comment: Won't I also want to be grouping by the CurrentBranchDate?

Comment: Does it matter when you are grouping by Quarter.  Maybe adding year to the grouping if you have more than one year.

Comment: I'll definitely need to add the grouping for the year. Is it just a comma separated grouping? I was having issues trying to add an additional grouping. I'll keep looking though. Thanks!

Comment: It would be : .GroupBy(x => new {month = (x.Field<DateTime>("ActivationDate").Month - 1) / 3, year = x.Field<DateTime>("ActivationDate").year})

Comment: Awesome. I'm still running into an issue with the AmountFinanced not summing. Here's my result: https://i.imgur.com/TPHyWhq.png. I should be getting amount financed: $175,650 ($77,200 in April 2017 and $98,450 in June 2017). It looks like it's just taking the first record.

Comment: Is there a way to call a sum around the "x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Field<DateTime>("CurrentBranchDate")).Select(y => y.Field<decimal>("CurrentBalance")).FirstOrDefault()" portion? Or would that not give me the correct result?

Comment: It would only add one item.  The add function is commutative so order doesn't make a difference.  I don't know why you code is giving wrong results without see the input data.  Modify my DataTable so I can see the issue.

Comment: I updated my question to have the data and sample code I'm using now.

Comment: You are awesome. I cannot thank you enough for your help and patience!